# Replacing ios7 mobile safari dropdown lists

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari, html-select

I'm trying to replace the default behavior of IOS7 mobile safari drop down lists (i.e. select tags) on iPhone. I find the default wheel picker nearly unreadable and it does't match the style of my other wheel pickers (using the spinningwheels library). I can't seem to disable the drop down from appearing even though I marked the element read-only (this works for input tags).

I realize I could just replace the select tags with input tags, but it would be just for iPhone and that would complicate the code. This is my plan B, but I'm hoping there's an easy way to prevent the default behavior. Any suggestions?